# Create a carpetplot with discrete values

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'd like to create a carpetplot with discrete values. For example I have these values:

```
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt
df_data = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 3], [2, 2, 5], [3, 2, 1]], index=['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4'], columns=['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])
```

I have also a dictionary to match these discrete values to a color:

```
    matcher_dict = {
    1: (236, 99, 92), 2: (75, 129, 196), 3: (244, 153, 97), 5: (135, 104, 180)}
```

I'd now like to create a carpet plot, and I thought imshow could be a way to work this out, as the documentation for imshow says

> cmap : Colormap, optional, default: None
>
> If None, default to rc image.cmap value. **cmap is ignored when X has RGB(A) information**

So I create a new Dataframe with the colors as entries:

```
df_color = pd.DataFrame(index=df_data.index, columns=df_data.columns)
for col_index, col in enumerate(df_data.iteritems()):
    for row_index, value in enumerate(col[1]):
        df_color.ix[row_index].ix[col_index] = matcher_dict[
            df_data.ix[row_index].ix[col_index]]
```

Now I expect this to work:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(
    df_color.values, interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto')
```

But all I get is a TypeError: Image data can not convert to float

The result I expected (and was able to create with an terrible inefficient code should look like this [Expected Result of the carpetplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VcPZ.png)

But this just raises an TypeError, Image data can not convert to float.

EDIT: If I use df_data.values directly (instead of df_color.values, it creates a plot, by using the default colormap. Is it possible to create a discrete colormap? (I didn't completly  understand the colormap concepts from reading matplotlibs documentation)

Comment: what is the type of `df_color.values`?  imshow expects a 2D array, anything else will be a problem.

Comment: a list (or precisely, an np.ndarray) created from the pd.DataFrame:[[(236, 99, 92) (75, 129, 196) (236, 99, 92)]
 [(236, 99, 92) (236, 99, 92) (244, 153, 97)]
 [(75, 129, 196) (75, 129, 196) (135, 104, 180)]
 [(244, 153, 97) (75, 129, 196) (236, 99, 92)]]

Comment: I don't have time to write a long answer this morning(sorry), but the very short summary is: the `Norm` maps you data from what ever range it is -> [0, 1].  The colormap maps [0, 1] (R^1) -> [R, G, B] (R^3)  (you can do alpha mapping too but that is a detail).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem. As assumed an discrete colormap does the trick. How to create one is described in [a scipy cookbook](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps), search for discrete_cmap.

So my working code would be this:

```
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt
df_data = pd.DataFrame(
[[1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 3], [2, 2, 5], [3, 2, 1]], index=['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4'], columns=['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])
cpool = ['#EC635C', '#4B81C4', '#F49961', '#B45955',
     '#8768B4']
cmap3 = plt.matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(cpool[0:5], 'indexed')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(
df_data.values, cmap=cmap3, interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(mappable=im)

plt.show()
```

Axes descriptions still needs some fiddeling, but it works basically.